# X-Path Query won't work in Google-Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath-2.0

I've been trying to use the following X-Path within Google-Sheets with the `=ImportXML function`

`=importXml("http://www.managetickets.com/morecApp/ticketSearchAndStatusTicketList.jsp?msgCount=23&outputEmail=&db=nd", "/table[2]/tbody/tr@[td]")`

But no matter what minor adjustments I try I continually get "#N/A" with a hover-text box that says "imported content is empty".

I know it's a valid x-path, I've cross verified it with 'X-Path Helper Wizard' chrome-extension.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong!?

Comment: If any validator is telling you this is valid XPath, then stop using it and find a better one. The `@` here is completely out of place.

Answer (score 0):

No, actually it's not a valid `XPath`. Note that `@` used to select an attributes e.g. `@class`, `@id`, etc. Also it's a bad idea to use `tbody` tag in your expressions as this tag is not always present in initial source code

So if you want to match table rows which contain cells from second table, you can use

```
/table[2]//tr[td]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on proper use of @

-- I tried using your example 

/table[2]//tr[td]

but got te same result in my cell. "N/A content is empty"

Comment: Could you clarify what exact required output you want to get? Try also `//table[2]//tr[td]`

Comment: The information at the URL provided is a table containing a column of ticket numbers and rows with specific information unique to the individual ticket from the ticket number on that row.

Comment: I'd like the X-Path to populate a google sheet with the table provided at the URL

Comment: Unfortunately, I can see only table headers without actual table content. Can you share `HTML` sample?